# Here Maps getMapPackageAtGeoCoordinates not Working and throws Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, here-api, here-ios

When I refered the HereMap documentation, i found we can download the region whichever we want using getMapPackageatcoordinates Method . I tried to download the region by passing my Current location which is a NMAGeoCoordinate. But my app crashes with error

I had also attached my code which i use to get the mappackage using getMapPackageatcoordinates method

```
-(void)getMapPackage
{
_StartCoordinate=[[NMAGeoCoordinates alloc]initWithLatitude:12.878831 longitude:80.095566];
[[NMAMapLoader sharedMapLoader]getMapPackageAtGeoCoordinates:_StartCoordinate];
}
```

I had passed the expected data type for getMapPackageatcoordinates method which is NMAGeoCoordinates. But still my app crashes with the below error. please guide me what to do and which datatype should be passed to the getMapPackageatcoordinates method.

> -[__NSCFConstantString escapeURLQueryParam]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x101024968

Comment: How your method is called ? Is there a more complete stacktrace you can show us ?

Comment: -(void)getlocationvalue:(NSTimer*)myTimer
{
    NMAGeoPosition *position = [[NMAPositioningManager sharedPositioningManager] currentPosition];
    _StartCoordinate=[[NMAGeoCoordinates alloc]initWithLatitude:position.coordinates.latitude longitude:position.coordinates.longitude];
    [_mapView setGeoCenter:_StartCoordinate withAnimation:NMAMapAnimationBow];
    [[NMAMapLoader sharedMapLoader]getMapPackageAtGeoCoordinates:_StartCoordinate];
}

Comment: i just want to download the packages of the provided coordinates.

Comment: So you are calling `getMapPackageAtGeoCoordinates` and not `getMapPackage`. What about the stacktrace ?

Comment: Yeah GetMapPackage method is working fine and the Packages are downloaded perfectly.

Comment: @Zakaria I dont know about Stacktrace...

Comment: I believe Zakaria  means the error log , is there a more detailed error log ?

Answer (score 0):

Using the GetMapPackage is the trick to solve the problem.